# Configurar Share Gate

Tags: javascript, html

Como configuro o botão compartilhar para continuar, ele não funciona por exemplo compartilhe e continue, e também esta com um problema que quando a pagina e carregada devagar o texto é exibido , estou fazendo testes nesse site http://mundialfrases.com

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <center><p><font size="5">Mundial Frases</font> <br /></p></center>
    <p class="adl-outside-gate">
     <center><font size="5"> Por favor, clique em um dos botões abaixo para continuar.  </font> <br /></center>
    </p>
    <p class="adl-inside-gate">
      <font color="#FF0000"><font size="6"> Obrigado!!! Seu codigo é... </font> <br /></font> <br />
    </p>
    
     <center><table>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <div id="fb-root"></div>
          <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#appId=1097309690362496&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
          <fb:like href="" send="true" layout="box_count" width="55" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <g:plusone size="tall" callback="afterPlus"></g:plusone>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
              var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
              po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
              var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
          </script>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table></center>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ADL = {};
      
      (function(namespace) {
        
        function ViralGate() { };
        
        ViralGate.prototype.setDisplay = function(className, value) {
          var els = document.getElementsByClassName(className);          
          for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].style.display = value;
          }          
        };
        
        ViralGate.prototype.lock = function() {
          this.setDisplay('adl-outside-gate', 'block');
          this.setDisplay('adl-inside-gate', 'none');
        };
        
        ViralGate.prototype.unlock = function() {
          this.setDisplay('adl-outside-gate', 'none');
          this.setDisplay('adl-inside-gate', 'block');          
        }
        
        ViralGate.prototype.afterLike = function(event) {
          ADL.viralGate.unlock();
        };
        
        ViralGate.prototype.afterPlus = function(data) {
          if (data.state == 'on') {
            ADL.viralGate.unlock();
          }
        };
        
        ViralGate.prototype.afterTweet = function(event) {
          ADL.viralGate.unlock();
        };
        
        namespace.viralGate = new ViralGate(); 
        
      })(ADL);
      
      ADL.viralGate.lock();
      twttr.events.bind('tweet', ADL.viralGate.afterTweet); 
      FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', ADL.viralGate.afterLike);
      
      afterPlus = function(data) {
        ADL.viralGate.afterPlus(data);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolveu? Estou tendo o mesmo problema. A parte responsável pelo like é:

`ViralGate.prototype.afterLike = function(event)`

Talvez mudar `Like` para `Share-button` resolva.